# How to extract regex comment

Tags: regex

I have a regex like this

```
(?<!(\w/))$#Cannot end with a word and slash
```

I would like to extract the comment from the end. While the example does not reflect this case, there could be a regex with includes regex on hashes.

```
\##value must be a hash
```

What would the regex be to extract the comment ensuring it is safe when used against regex which could contain #'s that are not comments.

Comment: Hashes can also be in character classes: `[#]`. Here's a fun regex for you to parse: `a[#[b\[\]]\#]\\#` (matches  ab#]\  )

Comment: @Kobi: lol, you are spinning me out. I am a whitebelt regex guy.

Comment: Here's my regex with the trick regex from my previous comment (it passes): http://ideone.com/4w5Q0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a .Net flavored Regex for partly parsing .Net flavor patterns, which should get pretty close:

```
\A
(?>
    \\.         # Capture an escaped character
    |           # OR
    \[\^?       # a character class
        (?:\\.|[^\]])*    # which may also contain escaped characters
    \]
    |           # OR
    \(\?(?# inline comment!)\#      
        (?<Comment>[^)]*)
    \)
    |           # OR
    \#(?<Comment>.*$)   # a common comment!
    |           # OR
    [^\[\\#]    # capture any regular character - not # or [
)*
\z
```

Luckily, in .Net each capturing group remembers all of its captures, and not just the last, so we can find all captures of the `Comment` group in a single parse. The regex pretty much parses regular expression - but hardly fully, it just parses enough to find comments.
Here's how you use the result:

```
Match parsed = Regex.Match(pattern, pattern,
                           RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | 
                           RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (parsed.Success)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in parsed.Groups["Comment"].Captures)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
    }
}
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/YP3yt

One last word of caution - this regex assumes the whole pattern is in `IgnorePatternWhitespace` mode. When it isn't set, all `#` are matched literally. Keep in mind the flag might change multiple times in a single pattern. In `(?-x)#(?x)#comment`, for example, regardless of `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, the first `#` is matched literally, `(?x)` turns the `IgnorePatternWhitespace` flag back on, and the second `#` is ignored.

If you want a robust solution you can use a regex-language parser.
You can probably adapt the .Net source code and extract a parser:

- [Reference Source - RegexParser.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexParser.cs)
- [GitHub - RegexParser.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.RegularExpressions/src/System/Text/RegularExpressions/RegexParser.cs)

Comment: I chose .Net based on the OP other tags. If this pattern looks a little off it's because it's missing nested negated character classes: `[a-z-[c-e]]`, but they can only come at the end of the parent class, to it can parse the excess `]`'s well.

Comment: @Valamas - no problem! let me know if I've missed any interesting edge cases. I *think* I got it mostly right.

Comment: @Valamas - I've edited the answer to include `(?# those comments)`. Apparently, they exist.

Comment: Terrific answer using capture groups and showcasing .NET repeated capture. :)

Comment: I believe your answer is a more robust pattern and deserves the answer. But I have provided an answer using the `RightToLeft` option which may simply the search if the user is only looking for comments which are not in an `(?# )` block.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (if you run it separately on each line of the regex). The comment itself (if it exists) will be in the third capturing group.

```
/^((\\.)|[^\\\#])*\#(.*)/
```

`(\\.)` matches an escaped character, `[^\#]` matches any non-slash non-hash characters, together with the `*` quantifier they match the entire line before the comment. Then the rest of the regex detects the comment marker and extracts the text.

Comment: I am not getting any matches on that. Trying this through RegexBuddy program. thanks for explaining and helping so far.

Answer (score 1):

One of the overlooked options in regex parsing is the `RightToLeft` mode.

> extract the comment from the end.

One can simply the pattern if we work our way from the *end of the line* to the beginning. Such as

```
^          
  .+?            # Workable regex 
 (?<Comment>     # Comment group
   (?<!\\)       # Not a comment if escaped.
   \#            # Anchor for actual comment
   [^#]+         # The actual commented text to stop at #
 )?              # We may not have a comment 
$
```

Use the above pattern in C# with these options `RegexOptions.RightToLeft | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline`

> there could be a regex with includes regex on hashes

This line `(?<!\\)       # Not a comment if escaped.` handles that situation by saying if there is a proceeding `\`, we do not have a comment.